# Como saber qual erro do meu programa android?

Tags: android, android-eclipse

Meu app tá dando um erro que eu simplesmente não faço ideia de como resolver, aí eu copiei o erro que dá (no celular fica assim: " O aplicativo'nome do app' parou") podem me ajudar a identificar o problema?

> 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260): Process:
>   com.example.mensagemparaela, PID: 12260 10-14 00:33:41.677:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.mensagemparaela/com.example.mensagemparaela
>   .PrimeiraTela}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ImageView 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>
> 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
>
> 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 10-14
>
> 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>
> 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-14
>
> 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 10-14
>
> 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294) 10-14
>
> 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-14 
>   00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 10-14 
>   00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 10-14
>   00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.ImageView 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):
>     at
>   com.example.mensagemparaela.PrimeiraTela.onCreate(PrimeiraTela.java:32)
>   10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 10-14
>   00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
>   10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):  ... 10 more

obs: não sei se afeta, mas eu to usando o eclipse adt bundle, mas pra testar os apps to usando meu celular que já tem o lollipop... (não posso usar o Android Studio, meu PC não aguenta.)

Desde já agradeço

Comment: O erro diz que você está a tentar transformar(cast) um *Button* em *ImageView*. Veja os `findViewById()` da *Activity* PrimeiraTela

Comment: Boa tarde Alan, poste o código pra ver aonde exatamente ocorreu o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
android.widget.ImageView 10-14 00:33:41.677: E/AndroidRuntime(12260):
at com.example.mensagemparaela.PrimeiraTela.onCreate(PrimeiraTela.java:32)
```

A causa está na linha 32 do arquivo `PrimeiraTela.java`.

Você tentou fazer *cast* (converter) de um objeto da classe `Button` para um da classe `ImageView`. Essas duas classes não são compatíveis entre si.

Provavelmente você vai precisar trocar essa linha:

```
ImageView botao = (ImageView)findViewById(...);
```

por essa:

```
Button botao = (Button)findViewById(...);
```

Comment: É isso aí, tentou converter um objeto de um tipo em outro =)